# Xcode sqlite3,use "insert" but fail and defined 1

Tags: xcode, sqlite, sql-insert

I wanted to add a line to my table 'Cloth',but failed.I then set breakpoint and found the defined is 1.

Here's the code.

```
char *addCloth = "INSERT INTO 'Cloth'(Ckind,Ccolor,Cseason,Ctexture,Cstyly) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?);";
sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
int success = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, addCloth, -1, &stmt, nil);
if(success!= SQLITE_OK){
    NSLog(@"Error: failed to insert:testTable");
    sqlite3_close(db);
}
sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, [strkind UTF8String], -1, NULL);
sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, [strcolor UTF8String], -1, NULL);
sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 3, [seas UTF8String], -1, NULL);
sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 4, [texture UTF8String], -1, NULL);
sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 5, [style UTF8String], -1, NULL);
success = sqlite3_step(stmt);
if(success != SQLITE_DONE)
{sqlite3_close(db);
    NSLog(@"单品新增失败");
}
sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
```

}

and the run image:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbEJo.png)
it seems my 'stmt' is nil,so I doubt whether if my 'strkind' and 'strcolor'is Chinese character caused it.
Or something else where made this error?
Thanks

Comment: Call [sqlite3_errmsg()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/errcode.html) when the prepare or step fails.

Comment: @CL. I checked it.But I still don't know how it happened. It seems that SQL error or missing database，but how？

Comment: Edit the question to show the new code.

Comment: @CL. I'm so sorry to bother you. When I try to edit the question, I checked my code and database again, then I found my insert sentence had something wrong. I corrected it and it's no error now. Thanks a lot!